# Identifying duplicate data, and re-search database based on new user input

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, visual-studio

I have been able to identify if the value is duplicated or not but only for the very first value entered, it seems as if the first entry is being held as a search and it doesn't update the search when the value has been changed in the textbox. For visual representation see images below.

**Here is my method I have used:**

```
private void CheckContactNumber()
    {

        DataSet myDataSet = new DataSet();

        try
        {
            string strAccessSelect = "select count(*) from Employee where ContactNumber='" + addContactNum.Text + "'";
            OleDbCommand myAccessCommand = new OleDbCommand(strAccessSelect, conn);
            OleDbDataAdapter myDataAdapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(myAccessCommand);

            conn.Open();
            myDataAdapter.Fill(myDataSet, "Employee");


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Error: Failed to retrieve the required data from the DataBase.\n{0}", ex.Message);
            return;
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
        DataTable dt = myDataSet.Tables[0];
        if (dt != null)
        {
            if (int.Parse(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()) > 0)
            {
                uniqueContactNumber = false;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Here is the method of which the checkContactNumber method links to:**

```
   private void addEmployee_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string err = "";

        if (addFirstName.Text.Trim() == "")
        {
            errorFirstName.Visible = true;
            err += "Enter a value for First Name\r\n";
        }
        else if (!Regex.IsMatch(addFirstName.Text, @"^[a-zA-Z]+$"))//has numerical and has a value
        {
            errorFirstName.Visible = true;
            err += "Enter a valid First Name\r\n";
        }

        else errorFirstName.Visible = false;

        if (addLastName.Text.Trim() == "")
        {
            errorLastName.Visible = true;
            err += "Enter a value for Last Name\r\n";
        }
        else if (!Regex.IsMatch(addLastName.Text, @"^[a-zA-Z]+$"))
        {
            errorLastName.Visible = true;
            err += "Enter a valid Last Name\r\n";
        }
        else errorLastName.Visible = false;


        if (addFirstName.Text.Trim() != "" && addLastName.Text.Trim() != "" && addFirstName.Text.Trim() == addLastName.Text.Trim())//identifies if FirstName + SecondName is equal to each other.
        {
            errorFirstName.Visible = true;
            errorLastName.Visible = true;
            err += "First Name and Second Name must be unique\r\n";
        }


        if (addRole.Text.Trim() == "")
        {
            errorRole.Visible = true;
            err += "Select a Role type\r\n";
        }
        else errorRole.Visible = false;

        if (!Regex.IsMatch(addContactNum.Text, @"^\d{11}$"))
        {
            errorContactNum.Visible = true;
            err += "Enter a value for Contact Number\r\n";
        }
        else errorContactNum.Visible = false;

        CheckContactNumber();

        if(uniqueContactNumber == false && addContactNum.Text != "")
        {
            err += "Contact Number Already exist..\r\n";
            errorContactNum.Visible = true;
        }
        if (err == "" && uniqueContactNumber == true)
        {
            string addEmployee = "INSERT INTO Employee (FirstName, LastName, Role, DateOfHire, ContactNumber)" +
                        "VALUES (@FirstName, @LastName, @Role, @DateOfHire, @ContactNumber)";

            OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(addEmployee, conn);
            OleDbDataAdapter da = new OleDbDataAdapter(cmd);
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@FirstName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = addFirstName.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@LastName", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = addLastName.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Role", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = addRole.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@DateOfHire", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = addDateOfHire.Text;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ContactNumber", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = addContactNum.Text;

            conn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

            //addFirstName.Text = String.Empty;
            //addLastName.Text = String.Empty;
            //addRole.Text = String.Empty;
            //addContactNum.Text = String.Empty;
            addRole.DropDownStyle = System.Windows.Forms.ComboBoxStyle.DropDownList;



        }
        //Save It
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show(err);
        }
    }
```

[Here is an example image showing that it can identify if there is duplicate data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3WLr.png)

[This shows that I have re-entered to make it unique but it still says it exists.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qt9Et.png)

[This shows that I have closed the program and ran it again using the same contact number in image 2 and it then saves.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qt9Et.png)

Comment: Please read up on using parameterised queries, such as this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16466300/sql-injection-parameterised-query

Comment: Looks like you never set uniqueContactNumber to true. Is that the variable that you use to decide if showing the message box or not?

Comment: @Turophile when I tried using parameters I still couldn't get this to work.

Comment: @AndreaAngella sorry about that I have listed it as true already but right at the top of the program, I have set it as public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you click the addEmployee button when contact number is a duplicate uniqueContactNumber is set to false and a message box is shown. If you than change the contact number with a new one and click the button again the CheckContactNumber method does nothing leaving uniqueContactNumber with the value false.

You need to make sure to set uniqueContactNumber to true in that case.

You can fix it using the code below:

```
if (int.Parse(dt.Rows[0][0].ToString()) > 0)
{
    uniqueContactNumber = false;
}
else
{
    uniqueContactNumber = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, when I read your answer I didn't want it to be correct down to me trying to explore so many different methods then it comes down to a simple else statement, but looking at it positively I have finally got my code running, again thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend that you add a `UNIQUE` constraint to Index which contains the `ContactNumber` field for the Employee table and that you catch the error thrown by MySQL when a record is inserted which violates that constraint.

1. The first two images I see appear to be identical (https://i.stack.imgur.com/a3WLr.png, https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2SoA.png)
2. The 3rd image (XOE0Q.png, sorry SO won't let me post another link) appears to have a different number than the above two.

Thus, I think your code is doing the right thing unless the 2nd image was an error. If a different number was typed in for image 2 vs image 1, then your form is probably not calling the validate method again, upon further input. To verify this, use the debugger and set a breakpoint inside your `checkContactNumber` method and verify that it's being called again. Which event is this method bound to on the `contactNumber` input?

Comment: I have re-edited the images I am not too sure what happened there but it will make sense now, or should.